# Node.js - variable outside request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react application. There is an expression in the server file:

```
app.use(_.get('*', function *() {
    if (isMobile){
        yield this.render('mobile', {
            seo,
            state: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(state)),
            body: renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <RouterContext {...props}/>
                </Provider>
            )
        });
    } else {
    yield this.render('index', {
        seo,
        assets: assets;
        state: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(state)),
        body: renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...props}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    })
}
}))
```

I need to add another variable to check request before rendering, example:

```
const request = require('request');
request({
            url: reqUrl,
            json: true
        }, function (error, body) {
        if (!error && body.type == "online") {
            yield this.render('index', {
        seo,
        assets:  assets, 
        state: encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(state)),
        body: renderToString(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...props}/>
            </Provider>
        )
    })
        } else {
         //use code above, starts with `if`
        })
```

But i get an error: `yield is a reserved word`

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? Is it possible to render only after the request is sent? I can not understand how

The server rendered before the code was executed, so I will always get `undefined` when I try to put the response from the function into a global variable

Comment: You can only use `yield` inside generators.

Comment: Tell me, please, what should I do in my case? I still can not understand :(